# Почему ModelState не видит ошибку валидации

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Всем привет, подскажите пожалуйста почему `ModelState.IsValid` не видит ошибку валидации при присваивании заведомо неправильной модели свойству `ViewData.Model`?. 
Вот класс

```
public class Class1
    {        
        [Required]
        public string EnterName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string EnterMessage { get; set; }        
    }
```

А вот метод действия

```
public ActionResult Index(string EnterName, string EnterMessage)
        {
            ViewData.Model = new MvcApplication5.Models.Class1();

            ViewBag.M = ModelState.IsValid;

            return View();
        }
```

Как видно из кода действия, то я присваиваю класс с пустыми свойствами, а это не допустимо из-за атрибутов `[Required]` однако `ViewBag.M = ModelState.IsValid;` выдает true. Почему ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что

> Объект ModelState сохраняет все значения, которые пользователь ввел для свойств модели, а также все ошибки, связанные с каждым свойством и с моделью в целом. Если в объекте ModelState имеются какие-нибудь ошибки, то свойство ModelState.IsValid возвратит false

проверка выполняется для введённой пользователем модели.

В чём сакральный смысл проверять внутренние данные?

Comment: Спасибо. То есть в этот объект сохраняется только результат привязки данных модели ? То что было введено в форме, потом идет в качестве аргументов для метода действия и потом это валидируется и результаты валидации пишуться в `ModelState` ?

Comment: @polyakov_s, не помню точно. И не помню, можно ли как-то явно вызвать валидацию. Но смысла проверять собственные данные на валидность я не вижу. Если форму засабмитят с такими, то должно работать. И вообще, вроде модель обычно в аргумент View суётся, а не так.